# 10 years UK ban, now married to UK national, can I apply for a spouse visa?

Tags: uk-visa

I’m a Nigerian. I applied for UK visa in 2016 through an Agent and I was placed under V3.6 because the agent made a mistake in my company registration letter. Then I applied for the UK visa again in 2020 because my girlfriend was pregnant and she plan to give birth in UK. The visa was deny and my 10 years ban was activated. Now I’m married to my UK British wife and I have a son with her, Who is a British now. Do I have a solution to this problem? Can my UK 10 years ban be lifted now? Can I apply for spouse visa rather than the visitor visa have been applying for ? I have our marriage certificate now. I need to be in my spouse and son’s country. Would my previous 10 years ban affect my spouse visa

Comment: Your situation is complicated, and a ban is very serious. Rather than relying on random people on the internet, you should consult a UK solicitor who's familiar with UK immigration. You can find one through https://www.lawsociety.org.uk or https://www.ilpa.org.uk.

Comment: What prompted the ban? You should have received a letter explaining the reasons.  Please edit the question to add an image of the letter with identifying information blocked out.

Answer (score -1):

the best solution for such complicated case is to consult an Immigration Advisor , and to my best Knowledge that adviser -usually a Lawyer- would appeal the ban based on your case facts.
I found a case of a Nigerian citizen with ***TEN YEAR BAN TO ENTER THE UK OVERTURNED***

[https://www.penningtonslaw.com/case-studies/ten-year-ban-to-enter-the-uk-overturned][1]

Comment: The link is dead. A lawyer or solicitor is not the same thing as an "Immigration Advisor"...whatever that is. Downvoted.